# hostgator - PHP - MYSQL cannot connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a comman problem with a non-comman situation.
When I try to connect to mysql server hosted in HOSTGATOR servers I am getting this error:

```
Could not connect to database. SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file.
```

The sollution is very simple and detials in here : 
http://www.phpro.org/articles/Database-Connection-Failed-Mysqlnd-Cannot-Connect-To-MySQL.html

But....
HostGator doen't want to change the "my.cnf" file! 
And most of the queries on this tutorial are denied because of my privilages.

Is there any other solution out there I am missing?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd ask the hoster for support.

Comment: Have you tried the last fix, which don't need change in `my.cnf`? but you may need a successful connection to do this.

Comment: hostgator support are not helping mw with it...I feel like I am talking to 12 years old kid.

Answer (score 0):

See Hostgator  [**help**](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/sql-connection-strings)

The following code uses [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for connection .

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
  //SELECT,INSERT queries here

}  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]'). $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
}  
// close the connection
$DBH = null;
?>
```